# Onsen UI tags not doing anything

Tags: jquery, angularjs, cordova, parse-platform, onsen-ui

I hope that this isn't too trivial, but I have a cordova app that I am building.  I have used cordova before and used onsen and I've tried to mirror what I've done before as closely as possible, but I am not getting anything from onsen to take effect.  Here is the index page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
distributed with this work for additional information
regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
"License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
software distributed under the License is distributed on an
"AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
 KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
specific language governing permissions and limitations
under the License.
-->
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />

    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.css"></link>-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/onsen/css/onsenui.css">  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/onsen/css/topcoat-mobile-onsen-green.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.2.19.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/onsen/js/angular/angular.js"></script>    
    <script src="lib/onsen/js/onsenui.js"></script> 

    <title>Top 100</title>
</head>
<body>
    <ons-screen>
        <ons-navigator title="List of Places">
            <div data-role="page" id="places">
                <div data-role="content">
                </div>
            </div>
        </ons-navigator>
    </ons-screen>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

All I'm doing in the body right now is loading a list of strings from parse with JavaScript.  Is there anything here that may be causing the onsen tags to do nothing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem by looking at my older projects with more scrutiny.  The problem was that in app.js I forgot to add this code

```
(function(){
    'use strict';
    angular.module('myApp', ['onsen.directives']);
})();
```

So, @runTarm, you were right to an extent.  I did need the ng-app tag, but also the code that activates onsen.

Answer (score 0):

The `ng-app` is missing, not sure if it is intentional (for manual bootstraping)?

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
```

Comment: adding ng-app had no effect

Comment: Then could you please show the content of `app.js` and `index.js`?